# Other methods of solving this question using calculus or something like that

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> If $$x^2+y^2=2015$$ find the maximum value of $$x^2+2xy-y^2$$

I have actually solved this question but as you see this question is apparently of number theory and I have solved this using trigonometry. I want to know about other methods of solving this question. If they include just number theory concepts then that will be even better. I am sharing my attempt as an answer below. Any contribution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with number theory.

Comment: Why do you think this has to do with number theory?

Comment: @lulu I thought that this question involves some kind of factorisation and things like that ...which we do in number theory

Comment: These aren't integers!  At least there is nothing in the problem statement that suggests that they are, so factoring methods aren't applicable.

Comment: You probably mean the methods of calculus, not of number theory. Please edit your question respectively (including the tags).

Comment: See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1278112p6712217 on AoPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like  [Maximum value of an expression by equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671143/maximum-value-of-an-expression-by-equation/4671149#4671149)

let $x=my$  and $$x^2+2xy-y^2=c$$

As $xy\ne0,$

$$\dfrac c{2015}=\dfrac{1+2m-m^2}{1+m^2}$$

$$\iff m^2(c+2015)-4030m+c-2015=0$$

As $m$ is real, $$4030^2\ge4(c^2-2015^2)\iff c^2\le2(2015^2)$$

$$-2015\sqrt2\le c\le2015\sqrt2$$

Comment: I really like this answer...and one more thing... I've also taken help from your answers (when I was studying trigonometry) that you wrote on how to find maximum or minimum value of certain trigonometric expression....we assume it to be S and then find discriminant and ....

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, Thanks for the complement. Nice to hear I could help someone!

Answer (score 8):

Let $x=\sqrt{2015}\cos a$ and $y=\sqrt{2015}\sin a$

Then we can say that $$x^2-y^2+2xy=2015(\cos2a+\sin2a)$$
$$=2015\sqrt2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2a\right)$$
Hence $$\textrm{max}(x^2-y^2+2xy)=2015\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 2):

The method you have used is the shorter one and easier too.

Alternative( using calculus) :

$f( x, y) =x^2+2xy-y^2$

and $g(x, y) =x^2+y^2-2015$

Let $\lambda$ be a parameter.Then by solving $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ and $g(x, y) =0$ , we get points of extrema of $f(x,y)$ on $g(x,y)=0$.

Then we can check the function values of $f$ at points of extrema to determine maxima and minima.

This method is known as [Lagrange Multipliers method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Answer (score 2):

Let's determine what condition shall $\lambda$ satisfy if $x^2+2xy-y^2\le \lambda(x^2+y^2)$.

$x^2+2xy-y^2\le \lambda(x^2+y^2)\Longleftrightarrow (\lambda-1)x^2-2xy+(\lambda+1)y^2\ge 0$. It is necessary that $\lambda\ge 1$, otherwise $(x,y)=(1,0)$ will make $LHS<0$. It is also necessary that $\forall y\ne 0$,  $(\lambda-1)x^2-2xy+(\lambda+1)y^2\ge 0$, i.e. $ (\lambda-1)(\frac{x}{y})^2-2(\frac{x}{y})+(\lambda+1)\ge 0$
i.e. $\forall t\ne0$ $(\lambda-1)t^2-2t+(\lambda+1)\ge 0$. Let $\Delta>0$ we yield $\lambda^2\ge 2$. Combine this with $\lambda\ge 1$ we have $\lambda\ge\sqrt{2}$, which is also sufficient for it passes the $y=0$ test $\Longrightarrow x^2+2xy-y^2\le \sqrt{2}(x^2+y^2)=2015\sqrt{2}$. I shall leave it to you to check the equality can hold.

Answer (score 2):

Solve for $y$:$$y=\pm\sqrt{2015-x^2}$$Substitute into the second expression: $$x^2+2xy-y^2=2x^2+2x\sqrt{2015-x^2}-2015$$Take the derivative of this function and set it equal to zero: $$4x+2\sqrt{2015-x^2}-\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{2015-x^2}}=0\implies2\sqrt{2015-x^2}-\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{2015-x^2}}=-4x$$Square both sides: $$4030-24x^2+\frac{4x^2}{2015-x^2}=0\implies4030*2015-4030x^2-24*2015x^2+24x^4+4x^2=0$$Make the substitution $v=x^2$ and you will get two solutions. Substitute them back into $x^2+2xy-y^2$ and the one that gives the bigger answer is the answer.

Comment: I think the middle term is $-24x^2$ not $-26x^2$. And İ can solve quadratic equations with big coefficients by using  computer only. :(

Comment: @BobDobbs Seems like I need to do a bit of arithmetic review. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, the extrema happen when when $x^2+2xy-y^2=c$ is tangent to $x^2+y^2=2015$. So, by using the "$-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$-rule", $-\frac{2x+2y}{2x-2y}=-\frac{2x}{2y}$ and hence, $y^2+2xy-x^=0$ from which we get
$$y=(-1\pm\sqrt2)x.$$
If $y=(\sqrt2-1)x$, then from circle equation, $(4-2\sqrt2)x^2=2015$ and hence $x^2+2xy-y^2=2015\sqrt2$.
If $y=(-1-\sqrt2)x$, then from circle equation, $(4+2\sqrt2)x^2=2015$ and hence $x^2+2xy-y^2=-2015\sqrt2$.

Comment: I like this one too...I'm right now studying coordinate geometry and this answer will help me relate things in algebra with coordinate geometry